# How to prove two strings are equal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two strings with one word mismatch.
I have to prove these two string are equal.

```
let str1 = "/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/{{userID}}/reset";

let str2 = "/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/NGDemo/reset";
```

As per my logic these two strings are equal.
I need logic to prove above two strings are equal.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like using the equality operator (`===`) would be the way to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let regex = new RegExp("\/gateway\/v1\/onboard\/core\/v2\/users\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/reset");

let str2 = "/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/NGDemo/reset";
let com = regex.test(str2)
console.log(com);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, please provide some additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question

Comment: (Also, please read: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992))

Answer (score 1):

you need to use strict equality,if you want to check they are exactly the same, ie they're the same type too, just in case.

```js
let str1 = "/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/{{userID}}/reset";

let str2 = "/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/NGDemo/reset";

if (str1 === str2){
  // do something
}else{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: actually these two strings are equal as per my logic. as per your answer it will go to esle block . actually it have to go if block

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this :

use the back tick on your string to replace variables inside it.

here is a link that explains how ["Template literals work"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var userID = 'NGDemo';

let str1 = `/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/${userID}/reset`;

let str2 = "/gateway/v1/onboard/core/v2/users/NGDemo/reset";

console.log(str1 === str2);
```